# I can't get child elements of div with Watir

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I have the following div

```
<div class="GoogleActiveViewElement" data-google-av-cxn="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pcs/activeview?xai=AKAOjsudJRMvrlZlT45Ttm1RMAMHc5hcztNQCne-rhrSacn7IrQgGtuXg528lxeI6WNimjQpc3PAavA26eLFW3kl5SPgVbGKAANcnxVtND4V93Q&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzNad2i7_dWSoEAE" data-google-av-adk="2411428758" data-google-av-metadata="la=0&amp;xdi=0&amp;" data-google-av-override="-1" data-google-av-dm="2" data-google-av-immediate="" data-google-av-aid="0" data-google-av-naid="1" data-google-av-slift="" data-google-av-cpmav="" data-google-av-btr="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai=AKAOjst46QS0vYvgXay8v4GHNx4Ms1ynqO9tqoJLPRC2LfwmhqyQ59zjIZhsJte9uA4985Ka2X8xGz2pOUT0cQBhbOSEAQHkB63D7Y6SMtEdH6CCv8S4SOSvZgL1Brh1ME5Ld94DAGVluAIptWktdFT_ZCCBEc_7TEBMlo0an5s12yD4jvFJPtj8Xlpff-NzZl6Mw46aniYwUkUJKhD57l2FtTXB3dZkMs92oYJ0QV99C9vRNUK_eTyEhjHyfWgB4vISQNG-z-Ij7GWu8OQBtcrfAxJC&amp;sai=AMfl-YQKOGKDZUHDTBNxlyqZiNmP6_rrW9cOrc4NoFO_iGSYabzRGjq8jFel8ORQPBs_hBoBPblA_61rLgyLA7iF6ozRBdDqlUWuNVdBeSBynE4_p7_9jT1FsCsP2Vhfl_e9InY2xQ&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzHeCVx_Ynp6KEAE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;adurl=" data-google-av-itpl="7" data-google-av-rs="4" data-google-av-flags="[&quot;xz&quot;]">
  <a href="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjss-c9OKDawTcctAwsrHawUMGjOZsWgw7JBPC41cdgdzOIJxJi2ONzIwJVGtPzuprpuuKMuPnheb_ETS4X2Cx01-2QABoEA12N8YvXHnZDvRmk0wKM4zVvMCPefsWMPNAqcVJRUi5_hOLGeXP0LMe3B1BeC7vH_YTwij5DtK-OKYVneNOcvy7SAjDIN-NBahyE0_D-HppUSYm1RZdfio6shJXkzVSwnjjVvisGesN4Hq0eyb6OKUaZhQHBEF_c1yrcL2APxC5NlE7A&amp;sai=AMfl-YTS5eZFEApy5JXVRUMr1mwg0xqccIXUuatLkgOeojS6ezBrqwS--0_2TW-xpjdQFDflT2VEQ0eUqDASKUTrQt2QxQamcvU2ysxFH2Bx-YyS9nWpGsfeOvv-MU74ffMBnN5boA&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzGN9wZsT-r7jEAE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;adurl=https://www.hepsiburada.com/gunun-firsati-teklifi" target="_top">
    <div style="width:100%; height:90px; display: block; background-color:#8603d3;">
      <div style="width: 970px; height: 90px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
        <img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/2447781458133218807?" style="position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;margin: auto; height:90px; width:970px;">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get that img src but can't get childs of div.

```
irb(main):010:0> @bw.div(class:"GoogleActiveViewElement")
=> #<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>"GoogleActiveViewElement", :tag_name=>"div"}>
irb(main):011:0> @bw.div(class:"GoogleActiveViewElement").img.present?
=> false
irb(main):012:0> @bw.div(class:"GoogleActiveViewElement").a.present?
=> false
irb(main):014:0> @bw.div(class:"GoogleActiveViewElement").div.present?
=> false
```

Comment: Is the top-level `div(class:"GoogleActiveViewElement")` being detected as present?

Comment: It is likely that the entire section is not being displayed on the page. exist? will locate it, present? also makes sure it is visible.

Comment: Is it in a frame?   If you examine the element with dev tools what is the complete path to that element?